# How do I "align" numerator and denominator?

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I want to make `(n+1)` on the same line. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hfill` can be used to move the nominator to the left:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document} 
  $\frac{(n+1)!\hfill}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. I think I am seeking after some "simple" solution. I am about to edit my question.

Comment: @Chou See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an automatic way?

Comment: @Chou `\frac` could be redefined. In general, left aligned fractions look quite odd. Also an automatic way would not know, which alignment would get the best output for a particular fraction.